# Asterisk call through browser

Tags: voip, asterisk, pbx

Currently, we are using two version of IPPBX (VOIP) System in our office, which are CUCM v11 and Briker 1.2.

We want to call directly through web browser instead of using a soft phone (or any desktop based application). The API itself is able to call/receive directly to/from PSTN or any extension that are registered in our CUCM or Briker.

We have done a lot of research on the internet and have stopped with Asterisk.
Is it possible to make calls directly through the web browser with Asterisk?

Comment: ?? https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/dosearchsite.action?where=AST&spaceSearch=true&queryString=IPPBX+%28VOIP%29

Comment: Had already search on these site and not found what I looking for. Any idea?

Comment: Are you asking if there is software available to basically have a soft phone in a browser. I.e sip browser?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Absolutely correct, we looking to somehow to integrate with our web portal system. So whenever our user want to call they just click the number and they can connected to our CUCM or Briker (Asterisk) IPPBX.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to run some sort of java applet it would be possible. But this would be quite the endeavor. I don't know of any software currently that has this capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebRTC tutorial using SIPML5](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/WebRTC+tutorial+using+SIPML5)
Browsers can't naively talk directly with SIP/RTP, you will need some additional software (SIPML5) to convert the audio/video streams to codecs which are commonly supported by your browser, as well as marshaling SIP to/from the browser.